# Is command prompt limited to print 296 lines?

Tags: c++11, command-line, ide, command-prompt, outputstream

I wrote more than 7 programs that is expected to  print more than 296 lines in the command line. But my windows pc (32bit with Code::Blocks IDE) only prints 296 lines each time. One of the code was:

```
  for (int x=0; x < 300; ++x)
           cout << x << "\n";
```

First number the program above  printed was 4 (I don't know what it does with 0,1,2 and 3) and last number was 299 in 296th line. I guess something is limited there. But what, ostream in c++, my IDE or the command prompt itself?

Comment: Did you determine this by running your program and then scrolling up?

Comment: Yes...I scrolled through the whole cmd window.

Comment: Perhaps the program did output those first few numbers, but the buffer holding the scrollback information has discarded the oldest lines...

Comment: @steve Did you ever run a program that needs to print more than 300 lines?

Comment: I sure did. Before I posted my first comment.

Comment: If you right-click on the command prompt window's title bar and select `Properties`, go to the `Layout` tab. There is a place to specify the scrollback buffer size. It appears the default is `300`, since I've never changed this setting. Try increasing that.

Comment: I will definitely try what you said. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the method you used to check what number were output was by scrolling back in the command window, you're not seeing the first part of your output.

The scrollback window has a limit to the number of lines it keeps around. After you run your program and scroll back to see the number `4`, press enter 4 times and scroll back again. The number will now be `8`. This doesn't mean your program didn't print the numbers 0 through 7.

If you right-click on the command prompt window's title bar and select Properties, go to the Layout tab. There is a place to specify the scrollback buffer size. It appears the default is 300, since I've never changed this setting.